# Access images uploaded from mobile ms Teams App in Botframework

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams, botframework

When users upload images(or files) in the web msTeams Application, I can access the files just fine. But when the mobile msTeams App (on iOs at least, I was not able to test this yet with android) is used, the attachment format is different, and the url from the attachments cannot be accessed:

```
attachments [
  {
    contentType: 'image/*',
    contentUrl: 'https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/attachments/0-.../views/original'
  },
  {
    contentType: 'text/html',
    content: '<div><img src="https://eu-api.asm.skype.com/v1/objects/0.../views/imgo" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.skype.com/AMSImage" style="width:795px; height:389px"></div>'
  }
]
```

The contentUrl returns unauthorized (401), while the content source url that is inside the html tags is not accessible from my cloud functions that try to download this image to put into the storage. How can I extend my function to be able to download the images(files) that users share from the mobile msTeams app?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please test in on android too? This will confirm if it's by design.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT Hi, I've just tested on android, it's the same. Does this mean that the mobile App does not support this?

Comment: Let me forward this issue to our mobile team and will update with solution. Did you try [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload). on mobile?

Comment: @Manish-MSFT I just noticed, that if I use the attach icon in the mobile app, then it works, using the [node version of file upload](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/56.teams-file-upload/bots/teamsFileUploadBot.js). But my issue is, if I click the 'photo icon' in the mobile teams app to share a photo with the bot, neither content.downloadUrl is present, nor attachments[0].contenType = 'application/vnd.microsoft.teams.file.download.info', and the url's from the attachments are not accessible.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT I was able to fix this issue, sharing Images with the Bot is using the Skype servers, so the JWT token was missing for the request.

Comment: @seveneights i am facing the same issue, could you, please, explain how did u fix it? i haven't undestood your previous message ...

Comment: @AndreyMazur You need a Bearer Token when accessing the files from the contentUrl to download them.  c.f. getting a token here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0